# What is $\bigcap\limits_{n = 1}^\infty {(1 - \frac{1}{n},1 + \frac{1}{n})} $?

Tags: calculus

What is $\bigcap\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {(1 - \frac{1}{n},1 + \frac{1}{n})} $?

Comment: What can you say about the intersection of the first two elements? What about the intersection $I$ of the first element with the third element, and $I$'s intersection with the second element?

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @Neal - Can we say that $\bigcap\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {(1 - \frac{1}{n},1 + \frac{1}{n})}  = \emptyset $?

Comment: We must find $x$ such that 

$1 - \frac 1n < x < 1 + \frac 1n$ for all $n$. $1$ satisfies this, since $\frac 1n > 0$ for all $n$. Uniqueness follows from the Archimedian property.

Comment: @Runa: You surely cannot say that because $1$ is in each of those intervals, so it must also belong to their intersection, so the intersection must be non-empty.

Answer (score 4):

If $x$ is contained in $(1-\frac1n,1+\frac1n)$ for all $n$, then $1-\frac1n < x < 1 + \frac1n$ for all $n$, so ...

Comment: Can we say that $\bigcap\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {(1 - \frac{1}{n},1 + \frac{1}{n})}  = \emptyset $?

Comment: @Runa Of course we can say that...we'd be mistaken, but we can say that. Are you trying to understand these answers?

Answer (score 2):

$(1−\frac 1n,1+\frac 1n)$ is an interval over the real numbers.

if $n>m: \\
(1−\frac 1n,1+\frac 1n) \subset (1−\frac 1m,1+\frac 1m)$

$(1−\frac 1m,1+\frac 1m) \cap (1−\frac 1n,1+\frac 1n) = (1−\frac 1n,1+\frac 1n)$

So, what happens when n gets to be very large?

Comment: Are you sure about the fact that $(1−\frac 1m,1+\frac 1m)\subset (1−\frac 1n,1+\frac 1n)$? For $n=2$ and $m=1$, we have $I_n=(\frac 12,\frac 32)$, while $I_m=(0,2)$. The inclusion goes the other direction.

Comment: @bartgol  Thanks, when I first read this question I saw Union, and not Intersection.  When I realized I was answering the wrong question, I must not have done a very good job cleaning up the work that I had started.